# AWS EC2 doesnt run my User Data on inital launch [Windows Server 2019][Powershell]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am automating an initial launch Process for EC2-Instances with Windows as the OS and i am using a Powershell script. The script is working perfectly fine for itself, as i tested it without passing to userdata of the EC2 Instance in Clouformation.

**Without running this Script i am not able to connect to the machine** because i am working on dedicated Domain and the machine first needs to join this domain.

As told in the AWS Documentation i am using User Data to pass the Script to Instance with the dedicated `<powershell></powershell>` tags, that should run on the inital StartUp of the Machine. I Startup my Machine and pass my Script via **Cloudformation**

However, after many troubleshooting i got to one of my Machines and i get this Log of the UserData Execution, that was on launch:

```
2023/04/24 14:55:26Z: Begin user data script process.
2023/04/24 14:55:27Z: Unable to parse <persist> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2023/04/24 14:55:27Z: Sending telemetry bool: IsUserDataScheduledPerBoot
2023/04/24 14:55:27Z: Unregister the scheduled task to persist user data.
2023/04/24 14:55:34Z: Unable to parse <runAsLocalSystem> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2023/04/24 14:55:34Z: Unable to parse <script> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2023/04/24 14:55:34Z: Unable to parse <powershellArguments> tags. This can happen when tags are unmatched or poorly formed.
2023/04/24 14:55:34Z: <powershell> tag was provided.. running powershell content
2023/04/24 14:57:36Z: Userdata:  is currently executing. To end it kill the process with id: 184
2023/04/24 14:58:18Z: User data script completed.
```

It seems for me that it had a timeout for a reason i dont know. Also i tested it with the EC2Launch Settings and ran my UserData after every boot

[EC2Launch Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w96t.png) and with the Tag `<persist>true</true>`
This worked for me but it shouldnt run on every boot and i shouldnt be logged in to the instance before i can run my Script. **It should run like dedicated User Data only once at the startup of the instance.**

I have tried passing the User Data manually via AWS Console it didnt work. Maybe its the Base image if the configuration of the EC2Launcher but i cannot configure them as i need without connecting first to the machine, which is for my case not possible

Comment: `<persist>true</true>` seems to be a typo, specifically in the end tag.